# Serialize a vector of serializable/serialized elements

Tags: arrays, vector, serialization, rust

If we have a vector of serializable elements, how to serialize the vector?

In particular, how to process if each serialized element is a byte array (e.g [u8; 56])?

```
let mut byte_stream = data
    .iter()
    .map(|x| x.to_bytes())
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

This snippet produces a variable of type `Vec<[u8; 56]>`.

To transmit data, I plan to use `std::io::write` but it requires a byte slice `&[u8]`.

Comment: Most straight forward approach is likely using `&byte_stream[..]`, which should give you a `&[u8]`. If you using a serialization framework, it's common that it would implement impl a `Serialize` trait for `Vec<T: Serialize>`, to be able to compose serializations.

Comment: I already tried it. `&byte_stream[..]` returns  `& [[u8; 56]]` not `&[u8]`.

Comment: This approach is equivalent with `.as_slice()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Vec` by [`flatten()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten)ing it:

```rust
data.iter()
    .map(|x| x.to_bytes())
    .flatten()
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

But if you immediately want to pass it into a writer, you don't need to collect it first. You can just loop over the iterator and write multiple times.